# Geometry Probability

Tags: geometry

A circular dartboard has a radius of 2 meters and a red circle in the center. Assume you hit the  dartboard at a random point. For what radius of the red circle is the probability of hitting red 0.6?

Comment: That would be when the red circle covers 60% of the board...  Do you have a way to calculate the area of circles?

Comment: pie times radius squared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for $\frac{A_{red}}{A_{total}} = 0.6$
$$ \frac{\pi r^2}{\pi (2)^2} = 0.6 $$
Solve for $r$ :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ denote the set of points in the red circle, $C$ denote the whole circle, and $\mu(S)$
denote the area of any set $S$. Your question is then to solve for the radius $r$ of the red circle like so:
$$\frac{\mu(R)}{\mu(C)} = \frac{\pi r^2}{4\pi} = .6$$

Solving for $r$, we have that $r = \sqrt{2.4}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The probability of the point falling between a distance r and r + dr from the center
is the ratio of the area of the corresponding annulus to the area of the whole circle